# independent linear combination of jointly normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I need to find for what coefficients $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ the random variables $W$,$Z$ which are described below are independent:
\begin{align}
W = aX + bY
\end{align}
\begin{align}
Z = cX + dY
\end{align}
and we know that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal.

I know that any two linear combinations of jointly normal random variables are jointly normal themselves and their correlation coefficient is given by:
\begin{align}
\rho_{zw} = \frac{ac\sigma_{x}^2 + (ad+bc)\rho \sigma_y \sigma_x + bd\sigma_y^2}{\sigma_z\sigma_w}
\end{align}
and I know that $2$ Jointly normal random variables are independent if their correlation coefficient is $0$, but I'm wondering if there is any other way to determine $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$

Comment: Your answer is all there is.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for $a,b,c,d$ is obviously not unique. However, if you are interested in finding a particular transformation to decorrelate a random normal vector $\mathbf{X}$ with $\operatorname{Cov}[\mathbf{X},\mathbf{X}]=\mathbf{\Sigma}$, one way would be to use the [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices) of covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{Q^T}$, and perform the transformation $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{Q^T}\mathbf{X}$.

Then:
$$\operatorname{Cov}[\mathbf{Y},\mathbf{Y}]=\mathbf{Q^T}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{\Lambda}$$

As the covariance is a diagonal matrix, the components of $\mathbf{Y}$ are uncorrelated normal variables, therefore independent.

You may also look at the [whitening transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation).